# Copy visible cells to clipboard to be pasted in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, clipboard, rtf

I am pretty new into coding in Excel and VBA, and I have been trying to make a VBA button to copy only visible cells in a defined range to clipboard.

And with the copied to be able to paste into Word as text (probably rich text?) without creating a table, but keeping only the text formatting (font, font size, fontstyle) and not cell formatting (background color etc.).

I am hindered in the second part, albeit being pretty simple, I have searched a lot on different forums to find a solution.

First *possible* solution would have all of the selection pasted into a cell as text (with no formatting), and afterward pasting the selected into Word. My code works, but I am missing the font styling option for each selected cell.

```
Private Sub KopierTekst_Click()
    Dim cell As Range, SelectedRange As Range

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Activate
    
    Set KopiCelle = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("B1")
    
    KopiCelle.value = ""
    
    Set SelectedRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:A50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each cell In SelectedRange
            If Len(cell & vbNullString) > 0 And cell.Characters.Font.Bold = True Then
                KopiCelle.value = KopiCelle.value _
                & vbNewLine & cell
            ElseIf Len(cell & vbNullString) > 0 Then
                KopiCelle.value = KopiCelle.value _
                & vbNewLine & cell
            Else
                KopiCelle.value = KopiCelle.value
            End If
    Next cell


Dim TheText As String
TheText = KopiCelle
ToClipboard TheText
End Sub
```

Second solution would be converting the selected cell into HTML, and afterwards having the selection formatted in clipboard as being HTML content - but I havent figured out how to manipulate clipboard to see it as being HTML when being pasted into Word.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim cell As Range, SelectedRange As Range

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Activate
    
    Set KopiCelle = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("B1")
    
    KopiCelle.value = ""
    
    Set SelectedRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:A50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each cell In SelectedRange
            If Len(cell & vbNullString) > 0 And cell.Characters.Font.Bold = True Then
                KopiCelle.value = KopiCelle.value _
                & vbNewLine & "<B>" & cell & "</B>"
            ElseIf Len(cell & vbNullString) > 0 And cell.Font.Italic = True Then
                KopiCelle.value = KopiCelle.value _
                & vbNewLine & "<I>" & cell & "</I>"
            ElseIf Len(cell & vbNullString) > 0 And cell.Font.Underline = True Then
                KopiCelle.value = KopiCelle.value _
                & vbNewLine & "<U>" & cell & "</U>"
            ElseIf Len(cell & vbNullString) > 0 Then
                KopiCelle.value = KopiCelle.value _
                & vbNewLine & cell
            Else
                KopiCelle.value = KopiCelle.value
            End If
    Next cell
    
Dim TheText As New DataObject
Dim textString As String
textString = "<HTML><BODY><FONT FACE=Consolas SIZE=10 COLOR=BLACK>" & KopiCelle.value & "</FONT></BODY></HTML>"

TheText.SetText textString
TheText.PutInClipboard
```

A third solution would be without having the range pasted into a single cell, but instead into the clipboard, so we could keep the formatting of each cell - but this only keeps the text and no formatting once more....

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Activate

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim obj As New DataObject
    Dim textCell As String
    
    Dim textClip As String
    Dim MyData As DataObject

    obj.SetText ""
    obj.PutInClipboard


    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Range("A1:A50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
        cell.Font.Name = "Consolas"
        cell.Font.Size = 10
        obj.GetFromClipboard
        textClip = obj.GetText
        If Len(cell & vbNullString) > 0 And cell.Characters.Font.Bold = True Then
            cell.Characters.Font.Bold = True
            textCell = textClip & vbNewLine & cell
            obj.SetText textCell
            obj.PutInClipboard
        ElseIf Len(cell & vbNullString) > 0 And cell.Font.Italic = True Then
            cell.Characters.Font.Italic = True
            textCell = textClip & vbNewLine & cell
            obj.SetText textCell
            obj.PutInClipboard
        ElseIf Len(cell & vbNullString) > 0 And cell.Font.Underline = True Then
            cell.Characters.Font.Underline = True
            textCell = textClip & vbNewLine & cell
            obj.SetText textCell
            obj.PutInClipboard
        ElseIf Len(cell & vbNullString) > 0 Then
            textCell = textClip & vbNewLine & cell
            obj.SetText textCell
            obj.PutInClipboard
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

So it would be greatly appreciated if anybody knew a simpler solution to my problem or a fix to one of my three code snippets so it would work.....

Comment: VBA simply automates the software, so your first step should be to accomplish the task using the UI. Once you have determined that what you are attempting is possible you can then write the code to automate the process.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering.
It seems that it is possible to do the following in the UI, to get what I want:
1. Clear text box
2. Copy multiple visible cells (using CTRL+C)
3. Paste (using CTRL+V) to text box
4. Change font style and font size of data in text box
5. Copy all content of text box
6. Paste into Word with (CTRL+V). 
The text is only being formatted which could work without the correct font or font size.

However, when I am trying to do this in VBA, I cannot copy/paste into the text box....